# Internal Server Error with Craft CMS 3

Tags: craftcms

I'm installing Craft CMS 3 on a staging environment at http://staging.overlookpro.com and am having issues getting the CMS to show. I've installed Craft CMS 3 using Composer and selecting staging.overlookpro.com as my web root folder on my server. The folders that are installed are in this format: staging.overlookpro.com/craft/*.

On my local copy I am using MAMP on macOS and the CMS works completely fine. But for some reason the staging and production sites keep showing an Internal Server Error. I've made sure I had PHP 7 installed, but the control panel will not show.

Answer (score 1):

if it shows completely fine in your local environment, so make sure your URL should point to the web directory.

For admin login : `http://<Hostname>/index.php?p=admin/install`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use it in this format, then it will work out:

```
https://wedot.ch/index.php?p=admin/install
```

Or you can use it like this:

```
https://wedot.ch/admin/install
```

Answer (score 0):

Your URL must Point to your web Directory.

Use this URL: `http://<Hostname>/index.php?p=admin/install`